# offline version of yum install

Tags: linux, rpm

I have been installing quite a number of software using yum with my virtual machine.

I would like to find out if there is a way to obtain the rpm and dependencies rpm for offline install.

This is because the server which I am going to perform the installation does not have internet access due to security reasons.

Is there anyway I can specify the rpm to be downloaded as well ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This comes from a blog post I wrote some time ago.

You can have yum fetch all the packages and their dependencies on your VM, then create a repo from them which will then be used by your server.

Note that the VM should have just the minimal packages required for it to run; since you don't know what's installed on the server, you want yum to download as many dependencies as possible.

On the VM:

```
# mkdir /root/tmppkg
# yum --downloadonly --downloaddir=/root/tmppkg install <packages>
# chown -R root:root /root/tmppkg
# createrepo /root/tmppkg
# chmod -R 755 /root/tmppkg
```

Transfer the `tmppkg` directory on the server, let's say in `/opt`.
Then create a file `/etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo` on the server as such:

```
[local]
name=Local repository
baseurl=file:///opt/tmppkg
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
protect=1
```

Now run on the server:

```
# yum install <packages>
```

and the packages will be installed from the local repo. 
Once yum has finished, you can delete `/etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo` and `/opt/tmppkg` to save space.

Comment: I have several servers which will require the same set of software and rpm dependencies, how do I create a "repository server", for all other servers to download since you are using file:// for the baseurl

Comment: That's too long to answer in a comment, please see here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Configuring_Yum_and_Yum_Repositories.html In short, you have to change the baseurl to fetch the packages via HTTP or FTP, depending on how you set up your repo server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes yumdownloader (part of the package yum-utils) can download the needed packages. 
To download a package and its dependencies for offline installation you can use this command

```
yumdownloader --resolve <package name>
```

The order of installing them is determined by yum:

```
yum install ./*rpm
```

you can run this command in the folder with your downloaded packages that include all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tool called `youdownloader` like that:

```
 yumdownloader <package name>
```

it will install the package in rpm format.
and for downloading  dependencies

```
yumdownloader --resolve <package name>
```